# Removing lowest order bit

Tags: java, c, binary, bit-manipulation

Given a binary number, what is the fastest way of removing the lowest order bit?

01001001010 -> 01001001000

It would be used in code to iterate over the bits of a variable.  Pseudo-code follows.

```
while(bits != 0){
  index = getIndexOfLowestOrderBit(bits);
  doSomething(index);
  removeLowestOrderBit(bits);
}
```

The possible languages I'm considering using are C and Java.

Comment: what is meant by fastest? execution time, implementaion time or understanding time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uh ... In your example, you already know the bit's index. Then it's easy:

```
bits &= ~(1 << index);
```

This will mask off the bit whose index is `index`, regardless of its position in the value (highest, lowest, or in-between). Come to think of it, you can of course use the fact that you know the bit is already set, and use an XOR to knock it clear again:

```
bits ^= (1 << index);
```

That saves the inversion, which is probably one machine instruction.

If you instead want to mask off the *lowest* set bit, without knowing its index, the trick is:

```
bits &= (bits - 1);
```

See [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan) for instance.

Comment: sorry, i meant lowest...but still, i want to avoid shifting

Comment: Yeah but I think the whole point of the question is that you _DON'T_ know the index of the bit.

Comment: I think the OP meant if you didnt know which position the bit to remove was at

Comment: ooh, you get a +1 not for your answer, but for the link...that's w00tfully useful!

Answer (score 17):

This is what I've got so far, I'm wondering if anyone can beat this.

```
bits &= bits-1
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find the lowest set bit using `x & (~x + 1)`.  Example:

```
    x: 01101100
 ~x+1: 10010100
       --------
       00000100
```

Clearing the lowest set bit then becomes `x & ~(x & (~x + 1))`:

```
          x: 01101100
~(x&(~x+1)): 11111011
             --------
             01101000
```

Or `x & (x - 1)` works just as well and is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The ever-useful [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) has some [algorithms for counting zero bits](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear) - that will help you implement your getIndexOfLowestOrderBit function.

Once you know the position of the required bit, flipping it to zero is pretty straightforward, e.g. given a bit position, create mask and invert it, then AND this mask against the original value

```
result = original & ~(1 << pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to remove the lowest order bit. You want to ZERO the lowest order SET bit.

Once you know the index, you just do 2^index and an exclusive or.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is comparable fast, but I think it works:

```
int data = 0x44A;
int temp;
int mask;

if(data != 0) {   // if not there is no bit set
   temp = data;
   mask = 1;
   while((temp&1) == 0) {
      mask <<= 1;
      temp >>= 1;
   }
   mask = ~mask;
   data &= mask;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java use Integer.lowestOneBit().