# Unset the rightmost set bit

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)
>   [Removing lowest order bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472135/removing-lowest-order-bit)

`n` is a positive integer. How can its rightmost set bit be unset?

Say `n`= `7` => n = 0111.
I want `0110` as the output. Is there any simple bitwise hack to achieve the goal?

Comment: related, with explanation, both get & unset. [How to get position of right most set bit in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393100/how-to-get-position-of-right-most-set-bit-in-c/42747608#42747608)

Answer (score 19):

Try `n & (n-1)` where `&` is [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

```
n = 7
n - 1 =6

n & (n-1)=> 0 1 1 1   (7)
          & 0 1 1 0   (6)
           --------- 
            0 1 1 0  (done!)
```

**EDIT** (in response to the comment given by Forest)

```
n = 6 
n - 1 = 5

n & (n-1)=> 0 1 1 0   (6)
          & 0 1 0 1   (5)
           --------- 
            0 1 0 0  (done!)
```

Comment: @taspeotis : Check out the question again " How can its rightmost **set** bit be unset?"

Comment: Ah, yes.  I overlooked the word "set".

Comment: +1 Nice! I still don't understand how people see solutions like that so quickly.

Comment: @Toolbox: Either we've seen them before or we spent our childhood inventing them. For me it's a bit of both.

Comment: @Toolbox see Hacker's Delight (the book)

Comment: This throws an error if the number is equal to INT_MIN

Answer (score 5):

Your question is unclear.

If you just want to unset bit 0, here are some methods (with slight variations in behavior depending on your types involved):

```
x &= -2;
x &= ~1;
x -= (x&1);
```

If you want to unset the lowest bit among the bits that are set, here are some ways:

```
x &= x-1;
x -= (x&-x);
```

Note that `x&-x` is equal to the lowest bit of `x`, at least when `x` is unsigned or twos complement. If you want to do any bit arithmetic like this, you should use only unsigned types, since signed types have implementation-defined behavior under bitwise operations.

Comment: "rightmost set bit" seems perfectly clear.  It was just a poorly chosen example.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int clr_rm_set_bit(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    while(n & mask) {
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    return n & ~mask;
}
```

Comment: This is O(N) while Prasoon's is O(1).  Also, you want something more like `while(!(n & mask))`, but even that doesn't work for `n = 0`.

Comment: Actually this method (when correctly implemented) isn't `O(n)`. It's `O(log(n))`. And since n is bounded by the size of an unsigned int, you could also call it O(1).

Comment: Right, should have bounds checked for n==0 and n < MAXINT (or whatever the correct constant is for that)  At least I interpreted the question correctly