# How does this code involving xor actually works?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a variable that represents the XOR of 2 numbers. For example: `int xor = 7 ^ 2;`
I am looking into a code that according to comments finds the rightmost bit that is set in XOR:

`int rightBitSet = xor & ~(xor - 1);`

I can't follow how exactly does this piece of code work. I mean in the case of `7^2` it will indeed set `rightBitSet` to `0001` (in binary) i.e. 1. (indeed the rightmost bit set)
But if the `xor` is `7^3` then the `rightBitSet` is being set to `0100` i.e `4` which is also the same value as `xor` (and is not the rightmost bit set).
The logic of the code is to find a number that represents a different bit between the numbers that make up `xor` and although the comments indicate that it finds 
the right most bit set, it seems to me that the code finds a bit pattern with 1 differing bit in any place.
Am I correct? I am not sure also how the code works. It seems that there is some relationship between a number `X` and the number `X-1` in its binary representation?
What is this relationship?

Comment: but 7^2 inverts the second to reightmost bit. doesnt touch other bits.  7 is 111            2 is 010     so we have  101 as result

Comment: Not related to my question.I am not asking what a xor is

Comment: and you may have guessed 7^7 subtracts 7 from 7 which result 0

Comment: Intersting.I hadn't notice that.But how does this help in my OP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unset the rightmost set bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703964/unset-the-rightmost-set-bit)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4703970/253056

Comment: @PaulR:I don't think it is a duplicate.1)I don't want to unset a bit.I am interested in understanding how does this code give a differing bit between the numbers that make up the `xor` 2)I don't see in the thread you link some explanation on the relationship of `n` and `n-1` in their bitwise representation.

Comment: @tugrul:What do you mean by subtraction? `18^7` is not `11`.

Comment: two operands must have same bcd length

Comment: you cannot show 18 in one bcd digit. you need two. but 7 is one

Comment: for example: 18^13 both fits in two bcd digits and answer is 5

Comment: So you are saying that xor is a subtraction for numbers of the same bitcore representation length?

Comment: something like that. i dont know all definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of subtracting 1 from a binary number is to replace the least significant 1 in it with a 0, and set all the less significant bits to 1.  For example:

```
5 - 1 = 101 - 1 = 100 = 4
4 - 1 = 100 - 1 = 011 = 3
6 - 1 = 110 - 1 = 101 = 5
```

So in evaluating `x & ~(x - 1)`: above `x`'s least significant 1, `~(x - 1)` has the same set bits as `~x`, so above `x`'s least significant 1, `x & ~(x-1)` has no 1 bits.  By definition, `x` has a 1 bit at its least significant 1, and as we saw above `~(x - 1)` will, too, but `~(x - 1)` will have 0s below that point.  Therefore, `x & ~(x - 1)` will have only one 1 bit, at the least significant bit of `x`.

Comment: +1 for the first part.I did not understand the second paragraph at all.`above x's least significant 1, x & ~(x-1) has no 1 bits`. Why?

Comment: Rephrase: the _only_ effect of subtracting 1  from a binary number is to replace the least significant 1 in it with a 0.  So `x - 1` has the same bits as `x`, above the ls1 of `x`, so `x & ~(x - 1)` is all 0s above x's ls1.

Comment: I think I got it. So essentially we get a representation that is the least significant bit set (above and bellow bits are clear) that the numbers making up the xor defer?So the comments actually mean he least significant bit?

Comment: Just curious.How do you remember these stuff?Do you write code manipulating bits often?I am asking because I am always interested in what other do in case it can help me improve

Comment: "Do you write code manipulating bits often?"  [Yes](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html).