# Implementing bitwise NOT (~) operator perfectly (flipping the bits)

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

recently I was doing something related to bit manipulation. Up until now, I've tried many bit manipulations operations. But I am stuck at one operation.

Suppose I have int n = 5; binary (101), Now I would like to perform bitwise NOT on this int which I thought of the result would be (010) but rather the result was  -6.

But when I tried n = ~(-n) it gave me the result 4 (Although still didn't get the right output). Please tell why is it showing this type of behaviour is it because my int is not unsigned. Also please tell me the perfect way to implement the operation so I can get the right output. My main motive is to flip the bits correctly.

Thank you

Comment: An `int` has more than 3 bits. One of them happens to be the sign-bit as you correctly guessed. What is _"the perfect way to implement the operation"_? Do you want to implement bitwise not yourself? What operation do you want to implement and what is not perfect now?

Comment: Hint: `n = 5` contains a load of leading zeros (the number depends on the size of your `int`). You are setting those leading zeros to 1 in your output.

Comment: @churill I just simply want to implement NOT operation like (101) -> (010)

Comment: Correction: `int n = 5;` binary (0000000000000101) (at a minimum)

Comment: @GuyIncognito that much already know now. But how can I restrict the value of int up to a certain point? e .g. lets say I have 9 (1001) how can I restrict the size of int up to only first four digits and then implement the  operation only to those

Comment: You need to first find the most signficant set bit, construct a mask from that then do the negation and finally mask out the top bits. Your question is not clear and hence you are getting answers for exactly 3 bits which is probably not what you want.

Comment: If  `n` is 10, what result would you want?

Comment: @VaibhavBisht - You'll have to work out how many bits are set, and then only flip those bits.    That's involves more than the `~` operator.   You'll also need to be careful on handling the sign bit (elements of unspecified or implementation-defined [don't recall which offhand] behaviour on negative values).    Also, unlike `~`,  it means that applying your approach twice won't necessarily give back the original value (`101` -> `010` -> `001`).

Comment: @Jabberwocky if n = 10 (1010) then I would need to have the bits flipped i.e., (0101).

Comment: @VaibhavBisht you should have specified this in your question. Peter's and kaylum's comments apply to your problem.

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing the type of `n`. The ~operator is notorious for screwing up the type of its operand, so if you use it with a signed integer or a small integer type, implicit type promotion will cause havoc. This sounds like the problem  here to me.

Comment: @Lundin "n"  in here is of type unsigned int and also can you please tell me how ~operator would work in other cases (if int is signed int or long)

Comment: @VaibhavBisht It would integer promote the operand, then set sign bits on signed positive numbers etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

```
// assuming n is a 32 bit int
n = 5;          // n = 00000000000000000000000000000101
n = ~n;         // n = 11111111111111111111111111111010
n = n & 0x7;    // n = 00000000000000000000000000000010
```

With the `&` operator (bitwise and) you mask the bits 3 to 31 of `n`

you can of course contract the two last statements into one:

```
n = ~n & 0x7;
```

Answer (score 3):

`int` has more than tree bits, so you must mask the result of a bitwise negation like this:

```cpp
int flip(int n) {
    // bitwise AND with 0b111 = 7, this will clear all but the last 3 bits
    return ~n & 0b111;
}
```

The reason you got -6 is because `int` is typically represented in two's complement, where `-6` is all `1`-bits but ends with `010`. You must remove these leading `1`-bits to get the correct result.

Generally, I would recommend not using bitwise operations with signed numbers and instead do the following:

```cpp
unsigned flip(unsigned n) {
    return ~n & 0b111;
}

// this version works with any number of bits, not just 3
unsigned flip(unsigned n, unsigned bits) {
    unsigned mask = (1 << bits) - 1;
    return ~n & mask;
}
```

If you don't know how many bits your number has, you must first find the most significant bit. In the most naive way, it can be done like this:

```cpp
unsigned log2(unsigned val)
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    while (val >>= 1) {
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned variable_flip(unsigned n) {
    return flip(n, log2(n));
}
```

You can find more efficient solutions [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

For example:

```cpp
unsigned log2_debruijn(uint32_t val) {
    static const unsigned MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = {0, 9,  1,  10, 13, 21, 2,  29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
                                                          8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7,  19, 27, 23, 6,  26, 5,  4, 31};

    // first round down to one less than a power of 2
    // this step is not necessary if val is a power of 2
    val |= val >> 1;
    val |= val >> 2;
    val |= val >> 4;
    val |= val >> 8;
    val |= val >> 16;

    return MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(val * uint32_t{0x07C4ACDD}) >> 27];
}
```

Comment: what is 0b111 it's not a hexadecimal value. What is it? And why are performing AND(&) operation with it??

Comment: @VaibhavBisht `0b111` is a binary value, it's the same as `0x7` which is hexadecimal or `7` which is decimal.

Comment: @Jabberwocky but why are we only performing and (&) operation with 7

Comment: @VaibhavBisht Because you did not make it clear in your question that you want a general algorithm to handle variable bit widths.

Comment: @VaibhavBisht because the number 5 has 3 significant bits. This arrticle might be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393100/how-to-get-position-of-right-most-set-bit-in-c

Comment: @VaibhavBisht 0b111 is non-standard goo that won't compile on your standard C compiler. So this answer isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: @Lundin the question is tagged C++ and `0b` is a standardized prefix since C++14. GCC also supports binary literals.

Comment: @kaylum how can I find the variable bits in the above code.

Comment: @J.Schultke Yikes, yet another of them "C/C++" fiascos then.

Comment: @VaibhavBisht I updated the question to include a solution for that problem.

Comment: @J.Schultke I know I can find bits by numberOfBits = floor(log2(x)) + 1; or unsigned bits, var = (x < 0) ? -x : x;
for(bits = 0; var != 0; ++bits) var >>= 1; is there any other efficient way to do it

Comment: @VaibhavBisht I updated the question again. You can follow the link for various solutions, this efficient implementation will work for anything up to 32 bit integers.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find the most significant bit.  You can do this by shifting right by 1 until you hit zero, counting how many times you shift.

```
unsigned int bit = 0;
unsigned int tmp = n;
while (tmp) {
    tmp >>= 1;
    bit++;
```

Then shift the value 1 right that many bits, giving you a value of `n` rounded up to the nearest power of 2, then subtract 1 to get a mask with all bits below that value set:

```
unsigned int mask = (1U << bit) - 1;
```

Then XOR it with your value to flip the bits set in the mask:

```
n = n ^ mask;
```